# How to overlay MatrixPlot with GridGraph?

Tags: plotting, matrix, graphs-and-networks

I have a Matrixplot and a grid graph and I want to overlay them. But when I use show[g1,g2], it did come out what I wanted. I wonder how can I overlay them and make them like this? To make the points of the gird graph actually in the middle of the Matrix plot, like the pic below.
[image]

g1 = MatrixPlot[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}}, PlotTheme -> "Business"]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jW22.png)

g2 = GridGraph[{40, 40}]

[image]

Show[g1, g2]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]
mt = RandomInteger[1, {20, 50}];
gg = GridGraph[Dimensions[mt]];
```

An alternative approach to align the `GridGraph` and `MatrixPlot` outputs is to use the options `DataRange` and `DataReversed` with `MatrixPlot`:

```
Show[MatrixPlot[mt, DataReversed -> True, 
   DataRange -> Thread[{1, Reverse@ Dimensions[mt]}]], gg]
```

[image]

We can remove from `gg` the vertices  corresponding to non-zero entries in `mt` to get a picture that looks like the one posted in OP:

```
selected = Select[VertexList[gg], 
   MemberQ[Reverse /@ N @ SparseArray[1-mt]["NonzeroPositions"],
     PropertyValue[{gg, #}, VertexCoordinates]] &];

vC = AssociationThread[#, PropertyValue[{gg, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ #]& @ 
   VertexList[gg];

gg2 = SetProperty[Subgraph[gg, selected], 
   VertexCoordinates -> Normal[KeyTake[vC, selected]]];

mp2 = MatrixPlot[mt, DataReversed -> True, Mesh -> All, 
   ColorRules -> {1 -> Black}, 
   DataRange -> Thread[{1, Reverse@ Dimensions[mt]}]];

Show[mp2, gg2]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
mp3 = MatrixPlot[mt /. 1 -> Black, DataReversed -> True, 
   Mesh -> All, DataRange -> Thread[{1, Reverse @ Dimensions @ mt}]];

Show[mp3, gg2]
```

> same picture

Using `mt = Reverse @ matop` (where `matop` is the matrix in the first argument of `MatrixPlot`  in OP)  and

```
Show[mp2, 
 HighlightGraph[gg2, Subgraph[gg2, FindShortestPath[gg2, 173, 1386]]]]
```

[image]

To highlight the path shown in OP, we can use

```
path = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ (FindShortestPath[gg2, ##] & @@@ 
      Partition[{173, 439, 880, 879, 956, 1071, 1308, 1386}, 2, 1])];

Show[mp2, HighlightGraph[gg2, Subgraph[gg2, path]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
dims = {4, 4};  (* e.g. 16 nodes *)
grid = GridGraph[dims];
xyNodes = AbsoluteOptions[grid, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]] - 0.5
g = GridGraph[dims, VertexCoordinates -> xyNodes, EdgeStyle -> Gray];
info = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, dims];  (* fake data for bipartite graph *)
Show[{MatrixPlot[info], g}]
```

For more illustrative fake data and deleted edges:

```
allNodes = VertexList[grid];
allEdges = EdgeList[grid];
goodEdges = Sort@RandomSample[allEdges, Length[allEdges]/2]
badEdges = Complement[allEdges, goodEdges]
gBetter = Graph[allNodes, goodEdges, VertexCoordinates -> xyNodes, 
   EdgeStyle -> Gray, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabelStyle -> Red];
goodNodes = Apply[Union, goodEdges /. {UndirectedEdge -> List}];
rawinfo = Partition[
  ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, Times @@ dims], 
   Transpose[{goodNodes}] -> 1], Last@dims]
Show[{MatrixPlot[Reverse@Transpose@rawinfo, Mesh -> All, PlotTheme -> "Business"], gBetter}]
```